# Handling in role based permissions in next.js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

How to conditionally render Components based on user role.
Consider two roles A and B and /dashboard as the route.

//pages/dashboard.js

```
export const getServerSideProps= async ({ req, res }) => {
  const session = await getSession({ req });
  if (!session) {
    res.statusCode = 403;
    return { props: ... };
  }
  
  const userRole= await getUserRoleFromServer()
  return { props: userRole };


const Dashboard: = ({role}) => {
if(props.role === "A" )
return(
  <AComponent />
)
if(props.role === "B")
return ( <BComponent /> )
}
```

I am afraid this is the wrong approach and thinking if there is security vulnerability.
What other approaches are used in next.js to handle this condition.

Comment: _"I am afraid this is the wrong approach"_ - why do you think that's the wrong approach?

Comment: Security, I know the pages folder run in the backend , not sure if it's only getServerSideProps or the component as well.  Can the props passed by getServerSideProps be changed by the user in the front-end and render something else

Comment: Only `getServerSideProps` gets to run on the server-side only. The component's code will initially run on the server to pre-render the page, and then run on the client-side during hydration. _"Can the props passed by getServerSideProps be changed by the user"_ - no, I don't believe they can.